# Find average in intervals of each column without considering missing values using awk

Tags: linux, shell, awk

I can't able to find out average in each 6 rows intervals of each column. This is related to my my earlier post. I have the data with a number a columns like (here it is 2)

```
input.txt
1   3
4   7
30  //
//  3
10  3
40  1
//  90
//  22
//  11
//  //
//  //
//  //
```

I would like to use awk

```
awk '!/\//{sum += $1; count++} NR%6==0{print count ? (sum/count) : count;sum=count=0;}' input.txt
```

The above works for 1st column. So I can replace $1 to $2 for 2nd column. But I want to do it in the same command. Which I am unable to do.

Desired output:

```
output.txt
17   3.4
0    41
```

17 is the (1+4+30+10+40)/5; 0 is because of no integers and all missing value; 3.4 is the (3+7+3+3+1)/5; 41 is the (90+22+11)/3

Comment: why there is a `NR%6==0` ? you want a output every six line?

Comment: [edit] your question showing what is relevant from your previous question. Currently it is quite unclear what you are asking, what is your input, why isn't this code working...

Comment: What are the numbers in the output averages of ? Because nothing in your question averages 17.

Comment: @User112638726 I guess 17 is the sum of the 2nd column of the 6 first rows and 3.4 the average of the numeric ones (17/5)

Comment: @fedorqui Makes sense, but then what is 0 41 ?

Comment: 41 is (90+22+11) / 3, but 0 is... who knows. That's why I vote to close as "unclear what you are asking".

Comment: Dear @fedorqui and all. thank you so much for your replies. I have now edited my question an hope, it is now understandable. Because of an unavoidable circumstances, I could not reply tomorrow. I am very sorry for my late response and inadequate information.

Comment: @Will. thank you so much for your help. That works fine. But can you please suggest how to modify, if there are large number columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should sum each column alone. try:

```
awk '{if($1!="//"){sum1+=$1;count1++;}; if($2!="//"){sum2+=$2;count2++;}}NR%6==0{print count1 ? sum1/count1:0, count2 ? sum2/count2:0;sum1=sum2=count1=count2=0;}' input.txt
```

[UPDATE:]

If you have more than two colums to compute, you can use an array and traverse all colum each time.

```
awk '{
    for(i=1;i<=NF;++i){
        if($i!="//"){
            sum[i]+=$i;
            count[i]++
        }
    }}
    NR%6==0{
    for(i in sum)
    {
        avg=count[i]?sum[i]/count[i]:0;
        printf("%.2f ",avg);
        sum[i]=0;
        count[i]=0
    }
    printf("\n")
}'
input.txt
```

Comment: Can you please suggest, how to do it if there are large number of columns?

Comment: @Kayan I have updated my answer and shown you the way to loop every colum. Hope that can help you.

Comment: BTW, replacing `if($i!="//")` to `if($i~/([0-9])+/)` is more robust.

Comment: Does it mean any number of slashes (/////)?

Comment: Actually, no. It is a regular match, which means we only handle with colums made up by digits.